# What gems are required for Capistrano deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rubygems, capistrano

I'm a little confused about number of gems available for `Capistrano`.

I use `Rails 4.2` application with `Puma` server and I'm not sure which gems I need to add to deploy it with `Capistrano 3`.

So far I have:

gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'

and then:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/puma'
```

Some sources write that I need to include `capistrano/assets` and `capistrano/budler` as well, but some say that it's already done by `capistrano/rails`. From [GitHub](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/rails.rb) I see that some of them are auto required.

Moreover I'm not sure if `capistrano3-puma` is required and the only gem that is available for `Puma`.

Can you provide the minimal `Capistrano` stack for `Rails` deployment with puma?

Answer (score 0):

This is how mine looks like, i might be helpful.

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'
```

Installed gems

```
group :development do
    gem 'capistrano',         require: false
    gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
    gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
    gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
    gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
end
```

Comment: Do you need `capistrano/bundler`? What gems do you have installed?

Comment: @squixy I added the gems I used, in my answer above.

Comment: And what about this [bundler](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/rails.rb#L1)?